# Generic filter for datatable in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, typescript2.0

I'm having the data table for all my listing screen. Now I need to change filter option to generic like single text field to filter whole datatable. My code looks like below, 
In View file:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="filterQuery" />
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
            <table class="table table-striped"
                [mfData]="data | dataFilter : filterQuery" #mf="mfDataTable"
                [mfRowsOnPage]="rowsOnPage" [(mfSortBy)]="sortBy"
                [(mfSortOrder)]="sortOrder">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 10%" class="text-center"><mfDefaultSorter by="id_category">Id</mfDefaultSorter></th>
                        <th style="width: 30%" class="text-center"><mfDefaultSorter
                                by="name">Name</mfDefaultSorter></th>
                        <th style="width: 30%" class="text-center"><mfDefaultSorter
                                by="category_code">Code</mfDefaultSorter></th>
                        <th style="width: 10%" class="text-center"><mfDefaultSorter
                                by="status">Status</mfDefaultSorter></th>
                        <th style="width: 20%" class="text-center">Option</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
                        ....
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I'm having issue in filter code, It's not getting filter by given string.I could do filter for single column but I need to do for all the columns and it should be common for any data array object. My filter code looks like below,

```
@Pipe( {
    name: 'dataFilter'
} )
export class DataFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform( valueArray: any, term: any ) {
        if ( term ) {
            let filterKeys = Object.keys( valueArray[0] );
            return valueArray.filter(( item: any ) =>
                filterKeys.reduce(( memo, keyName ) =>
                  memo && item[keyName].toLowerCase().indexOf( term.toLowerCase() ) > -1, true ) );
        } else {
            return valueArray;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, could you expand a bit on what the goal is? Do you need to modify the filterQuery variable from multiple places? Do you want to use additional filters?

Comment: Sorry, now I have updated my questing please check this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
export class DataFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(array: Array<any>, value: string) {
        if (value && array) {
            return array.filter((item: any) => this.matchAnyKey(value, item));
        } else {
            return array;
        }
    }

    matchAnyKey(value: string, obj: any): boolean {
        let filterKeys = Object.keys(obj);
        let matchedProps = filterKeys.filter(key => obj[key]
                                                && typeof obj[key] === 'string'
                                                && obj[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1);
        return matchedProps.length > 0;
    }
}
```